# Send OTP from custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, one-time-password

I have built a plugin that shows 'Woocommerce Smart Coupons' store credits on email entry.

I need to verify they own that email through a one-time code emailed to the email address they enter. I just need to verify the email address belongs to them.

How can I auto-generate a code that is emailed/stored - I also don't know how to add a second field for entry or even send the email. I've looked at wp_mail(), but this doesn't seem to work, although our system sends many emails.

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Store Credit Checker
Description: A plugin that allows customers to check their available store credits using a shortcode.
Version: 1.0
Author: Brendan 
*/

// Register the shortcode
function store_credit_checker_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form method="post" id="store-credit-checker-form">
        <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        <button type="submit" value="Check Store Credits">Check Store Credits</button>
    </form>
    
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'shop_coupon',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'customer_email',
                    'value'   => $email,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'discount_type',
                    'value'   => 'smart_coupon',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $coupons = get_posts($args);

        if (!empty($coupons)) {
            echo '<h3>Available Store Credits:</h3>';

            foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
    $coupon_obj = new WC_Coupon($coupon->ID);
    $original_amount = get_post_meta($coupon->ID, 'wc_sc_original_amount', true);
    $remaining_amount = $coupon_obj->get_amount();
    $used_amount = $original_amount - $remaining_amount;
    echo '<div class="voucher-info">';
    echo '<strong>Store Voucher:</strong> ' . $coupon_obj->get_code() . '<br>';
    
    if ($original_amount > 0) {
        echo '<strong>Original Amount:</strong> ' . wc_price($original_amount) . '<br>';
        echo '<strong>Used Amount:</strong> ' . wc_price($used_amount) . '<br>';
    }

    echo '<strong>Remaining Amount:</strong> ' . wc_price($remaining_amount);
    echo '</div>';
}


        } else {
            echo '<p>No store credits found for this email address.</p>';
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('store_credit_checker', 'store_credit_checker_shortcode');
```